# Concatenate current value to previous value based on other column condition

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Pandas as well as Python.  I'm trying to mimic the task with Python similar to what I created in excel file to find concatenate the current value to previous value based on condition

if A = false then B, else current value in B column concatenate to previous value in B

```
A         B          C
False     "bird"     "bird"
True      "fish"     "bird,fish"
True      "Tiger"    "bird,fish,Tiger"
False     "Elephant" "Elephant"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to set up your `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    [False, "bird", ""],
    [True, "fish", ""],
    [True, "Tiger", ""],
    [False, "Elephant", ""],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

This creates the variable `df` containing the `DataFrame` in `Pandas`.

Now, use this code to iterate through the `DataFrame` and set each value:

```
last = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        df.at[index, 'C'] = row['B'] # because first one has no previous to concatenate to
    else:
        if (row['A']): # check A
            df.at[index, 'C'] = last['C']+','+row['B'] # if A is true, then concatenate previous B and this one
        else:
            df.at[index, 'C'] = row['B'] # else, use this B
    last = row # now set this row to the last one that was accessed, for the next iteration of this loop
```

If you `print(pd)` at this point, you will get the expected result.

Here is the full code I have used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    [False, "bird", ""],
    [True, "fish", ""],
    [True, "Tiger", ""],
    [False, "Elephant", ""],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["A", "B", "C"])

print(df)

last = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        df.at[index, 'C'] = row['B'] # because first one has no previous to concatenate to
    else:
        if (row['A']): # check A
            df.at[index, 'C'] = last['B']+','+row['B']
        else:
            df.at[index, 'C'] = row['B']
    last = row

print(df)
```

Comment: I'm unable  to implement successfully.  Noticed the column C will be created based on the logic.  but its assumed created in DataFrame.

Comment: @TVD Which part is unsuccessful? I have edited the post with the full code I used, please try it now?

Comment: @TVD can you also please elaborate on "its assumed created in DataFrame"?

Comment: Thanks, the code works partially, see the output from your code, when column A has "True", then it will continue to concatinate the previous value from C column.  The expected output will be 
    A            B            C
0  False      bird        bird
1   True      fish   bird,fish
2   True     Tiger  fish,Tiger
3  False  Elephant    Elephant

Comment: Thanks, the code works partially, see the output from your code below,  The expected output will be at index no. 2 - "True" - "Tiger" -" bird,fish,Tiger" instead of just fish,Tiger.  I think the code just ignore the condition at column A.   Ultimately, the result will be when A = "False" then C = B, when A="True" then concat previous row in B and current row in B.  Your code seems to ignore the column A condition.
    A            B            C
0  False      bird        bird
1   True      fish   bird,fish
2   True     Tiger  fish,Tiger
3  False  Elephant    Elephant

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment again - I seem to be getting the correct values for the full table and it checks for a at the line saying `if (row['A']):`, please can you check if that does what you need it to?

Comment: That's great! If this answer helped you solve your problem or fix your error, please accept it! @TVD